# jQuery How to show/hide only the closest span

Tags: jquery, show, show-hide

Here's what I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/dontbe/VBhYT/20/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.show_hide').click(function () {
    $(".commenthidden").slideToggle();
});});
```

My question is: how do I show/hide on click only 1 span at a time and not all of them?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Only the one you're clicking on? Use the `this` pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        $(this).next(".commenthidden").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

- Go to the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element to `anchor` being clicked in the current scope.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VBhYT/24/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `parent()` function and then find the relevant `span` within that:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".commenthidden").slideToggle();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VBhYT/21/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(".commenthidden").eq(0).slideToggle();
```

But you might actually want to toggle an item relative to the item you are clicking, which can be done using $(this)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.next()` like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        $(this).next(".commenthidden").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VBhYT/22/)